# Connection between black body radiaton and cavitys

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, boundary-conditions

I have some questions concerning the relation between the black body radiation and cavitys.

First of all, i don't see, why you can derive the black body spectrum from the mode density of the radiation inside an reflecting cavity. I do understand the mathematical side of the derivation and I now that an absorbing cavity with a small hole is the best approximation of a black body. But aren't the standing EM waves inside the cavity only there because the cavity is perfectly reflecting, determining the boundary condition of a vanishing field at the boundarys? How is this releated to a cavity with black, (perfectly) absorbing walls? Again, I do understand that the walls can't reflect all of the incoming waves, because there must be a possibility for the matter and EM waves to interact in order to establish the termodynamic equilibrium, but then how can you look at standig waves inside the cavity, if it is not perfectly reflecting?

The next thing I don't understand is how you can get an continuous black body spectrum while the spectrum inside the cavity is discrete. My thought is that you look on the limit of a cavity with infinite size. But this would suggest that the radiation inside a cavity actually can't be black body radiation because every real cavity has a finite size.

In this context I also don't understand how the following thermodynamic argument, that the energy density of the radiation inside the cavity mustn't be dependent on ist geometry, works:
If you connect two cavitys with a color filter that can only pass waves with a frequency f, and the spectral energy density at the frequency f would be greater in the first cavity, then more of the radiation at frequency f would get from the first cavity into the second then vice versa and the temperatur in the second cavit would rise.
I understand this argument from the thermodynamic point of view, but I can't see how you can bring this together with the radiation inside the cavity actually beeing dependent on the geometry because of the boundary conditions.

The last question concerning black body radiation is the following:
The frequency dependent mode density of the radiation inside the (reflecting) cavity is different for two and three dimensional cavitys. Does that imply, that extremly flat (nearly two dimensional) bodys also emit some other kind of black body radiation, a 'two dimenional version' of it? Or does this only mean that the black body radiation would look different inside a two dimensional world?
If it is the first, then the question of geometry independency rises again.

Finally there is another question I have, but it is only containing the radiation inside the cavity:
How can you say that only the waves following the boundary conditions can exist inside the cavity? What happens, when you put a (infinitesmaly small, so it woun't change the geometry) source of EM waves inside the box, which emits radiation that doesn't fit the boundary conditions? The radiation doens't know it doesn't fit the conditions until it arrives at the reflecting walls. In a real sourface, the field in the walls doesn't vanish instantly, because the charges need an amount of time to neutralize the field. What does then happen to the wave? Why don't you take this 'not fitting' waves into account when calculating the spectrum inside the cavity? And, what would happen if the sourfaces acutally would be instantly free of fields? I mean, the wave can't just simply vanish, can it?

I appologize for the long text and my bad english. I hope I can get some answers that will help me to get a better understanding of the black body radiation and cavitys.

Comment: You ask some interesting questions but to answer them all would requires long text and this would make this page less readable to other people seeking similar information. Please post your questions as self-contained separate posts.